# Converting an address string into GeoPt value

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I m using GAE/J 1.7
GWT 2.4
JPA requestfactory

I want to create a field where user can submit an address and save this value as a GeoPt in datastore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the address specified from the user, make a Geocoding request using the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), process the result and save it as `GeoPt` in your datastore.